# Trouble with simple PHP-MySQL form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I want to make a 2 field input form to my MySQL database. I connect to the database with no problem and even can post if I want, but the form is giving an error. (I'm already connected to the database at this point and I can test that is working)

This is the form:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Title: <input type="text" name="title" />
Privacy: <select type="text" name="privacy" />
  <option value="public">Publico</option>
  <option value="private">Privado</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This is the insert.php file:

```
<?  
mysql_select_db("copoetry", $con);
$sql="INSERT INTO Poems (Title, Privacy)
VALUES
('$_POST[title]','$_POST[privacy]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";
mysql_close($con)
?>
```

When I press submit I get this error:

```
Warning: mysql_select_db(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/content/02/6945202/html/copoetry/insert.php on line 2

Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/content/02/6945202/html/copoetry/insert.php on line 7
Error:
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: where do you connect to the DB?

Comment: In addition to the DB connection missing the query string isn't correct: do `echo $sql;` to see why. Don't forget to sanitize your input too.

Comment: $con is defined on my header, putting the PHP code directly in the file writes a blank row in the database so the connection works. However when put on a different file, I get this error.

Comment: You're not including the header file anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$con` variable should hold a connection to the database with [`mysql_connect();`](http://ar.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php), you appear to removed this line at some point.

EG:

```
$con = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass') or die(mysql_error());
```

Once you have done this successfully all your `mysql_*` calls will use that connection, so you could get rid of the $con variable anyway.

**ALSO**
Don't forget to escape your inputs so that are safe, inserting a `$_POST, $_GET` or `$_REQUEST` variable straight into mysql is very unsafe. Make at the very least you run [`mysql_real_escape_string();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on *each and every input you get from a form or cookie*.

EG

```
// Create a shortcut function somewhere early in your script
function mes($input) { 
    return mysql_real_escape_string($input);
}

// SQL Example
$sql = "INSERT INTO Poems (Title, Privacy) VALUES ('".mes($_POST['title'])."','".mes($_POST['privacy'])."')";
```

Note the string concatenation (using fullstop) to separate the strings/variables.

Comment: I had defined $con in the header, I didn't realize I had to define it again in the insert file. Thanks

Comment: Also thanks for the info, could you tell me where should I add mysql_real_escape_string(); ? I have no idea in which part of the code it should be. Thanks

Comment: @Liso22 updates my answer. You shouldn't need to redefine $con, my guess is it's just not available to this script for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `mysql_connect()`. Try adding this.
Also it's very unsafe to run a query with whatever comes from `$_GET/$_POST/$_REQUEST`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no connexion to your DB ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgotten to specify mysql_connect() command.